# Use of Keytool when importing certificate to create Truststore

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming, keytool

Allow me to preface this by stating that I am new to SSL in Java; I have only started researching it today.

I am curious if it is necessary to use the keytool to import a certificate and create a truststore. If this is the case, then how do professional solutions do this programmatically?

In any case, what is the code that is used to import a certificate from a server and convert it to a truststore for SSL authentication?

Comment: The key management for Java's SSL classes is centered around the [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) class. KeyStore and the supporting classes are going to be complicated for a beginner in the area. keytool is a useful command-line interface that use the KeyStore classes. A "truststore" in the Java context usually just means a KeyStore containing only trusted certificate entries.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk That's just what I was looking for. Thanks!